# Node.removeChild is not an object

Tags: javascript, removechild

I try to make a function who create a  `<p>` if it doesn't exist yet! And if it exist, the function delete it.

I have an error

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object.

Sorry if the solution is simple but I'm newbie in JS and maybe it isn't the right way to do form verifications :/

```js
function insertAfter(newElement, afterElement) {

  var parent = afterElement.parentNode;
  if (parent.lastChild === afterElement) { // Si le dernier élément est le même que l'élément après lequel on veut insérer, il suffit de faire appendChild()
    parent.appendChild(newElement);
  } else { // Dans le cas contraire, on fait un insertBefore() sur l'élément suivant
    parent.insertBefore(newElement, afterElement.nextSibling);

  }
}



function createMsg(textMsg, elementParent) {
  if (!document.querySelector('.error')) {
    var paraError = document.createElement('p');
    paraError.classList.add('error');
    var paraContent = document.createTextNode(textMsg);
    paraError.appendChild(paraContent);
    insertAfter(paraError, elementParent);

  } else {
    elementParent.removeChild('p');


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`removeChild` takes a `HTMLELement` as an argument no a string `p`.

```
function createMsg(textMsg, elementParent) {
  if (!document.querySelector('.error')) {
    var paraError = document.createElement('p');
    paraError.classList.add('error');
    var paraContent = document.createTextNode(textMsg);
    paraError.appendChild(paraContent);
    insertAfter(paraError, elementParent);

  } else {

    elementParent.removeChild(elementParent.querySelector('p'));


  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function may be helpful:

```js
function createParagraphAndIfExistRemoveIt(parent){
  var found=false;
  for(let p of parent.querySelectorAll('p')){
    found=true;
    parent.removeChild(p);
  }
  
  if(!found){
    let p=document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML='this is a paragraph';
    parent.appendChild(p);
  }
  
}

createParagraphAndIfExistRemoveIt(document.querySelector('body'));
```